# create-react-app hot reload crashes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using `Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)` with macOS Sierra and I see the following error whenever I save a file.
[image]

This is making `create-react-app` nearly unusable because I have to close the tab and reopen it whenever I want to see a new change. Someone had suggested to use Google Chrome Canary build which works fine with `create-react-app` but I now I have requirements to use the master branch of Chrome.

Comment: I use create-react-app with Chrome `56.0.2924.87` (on Sierra), and it works well without any reloading problem

Comment: @Freez strange, could be a problem with my mac